# possible to use javascript to change a html td into a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to use only JavaScript to turn one `<td>` in below table into a link?

For example,I want to use JavaScript to change the "Jill", into a hyperlink, instead of making changes on my html file.

Has anyone got a way to do it?

```
<html>
<body>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
   <td>Smith</td>       
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>        
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>        
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Do you only want the first `<td>` turned into a link?

Comment: Well the other <td> can also be turned into links as long as they point to the urls that i can specify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This puts all `<td>` elements in an array, which you could iterate through and assign a url to each if you want.

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
   <td>Smith</td>       
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>        
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>        
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="change()">Change</button>

<script>
function change() {
    var tdElements = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
    var oldStuff = tdElements[0].innerHTML;
    console.log(oldStuff);
    tdElements[0].innerHTML = '<a href="#">' + oldStuff + '</a>';
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this is what i needed. Used "window.onload = function(){}" to do away with the button so that it becomes a link once the page loads, thanks!

Comment: No problem. The button was just to illustrate the change.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS:  [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/h6w4eyje/)

```
<style type="text/css">
   td a { display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
</style>

<td><a href="#">Jill</a></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

The business rule is not really clear on the pattern for finding which `td` you want to replace, so I did this so you can easily modify your custom filter function.

```
$('table tr td')
    .filter(function() {
        return ($(this).text() === 'Jill');
    }).first().html('<a href="http://www.google.com">Jill</a>');
```